# SQL Reporting, combine multiple datasets for moving average

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008

Hi I'm pretty new to SQL reporting, but I have a seemingly difficult problem (at least I think it is ;-) let's hope someone can prove me wrong!)
I am in the process of creating a 'year to date' report, containing a moving average value of 12 months. This requires me to query all available results of up to 23 months ago (since the oldes value in my report is 12 months ago).
The way I solved it now (which works) is to make 24 datasets, each querying a month before the other. So ds1: query on this month, ds2: query on last month... ds24: query on 23 months ago.

Question is: is there a way to combine this in a single query?

The table looks like this:

```
DATE       ID    VALUE        DESCRIPTION
1/1/2012   12    'Text here'  'Text here'
```

The (simplified, there are some ineer joins and some more parameters) queries like this:

```
SELECT COUNT  Date, ID, Value, Description 
FROM Table 
WHERE (Date BETWEEN @parFrom AND DATEADD(month, 1, @parFrom)) 
AND description = 'Text here'
```

The reason I need this is because apparently it is not possible to make a graph when you do not have a dataset containing all available values.

Hope someone can help :)

Comment: Is there only one value in the table per month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like using Common Table Expressions for the dates in queries like this. Depending on your source table, this may not be the simplest answer, but it's nicely all purpose:

```
CREATE TABLE #Events
(id INT IDENTITY,
EventTypeID INT,
EventDate DATETIME)

INSERT INTO #Events
         (  EventTypeID, EventDate )
VALUES
         (   32,  '2012-1-1' ),
         (   4,  '2012-1-1' ),
         (   5,  '2012-2-3' ),
         (   4,  '2012-2-25' ),
         (   34,  '2012-3-1' ),
         (   4,  '2012-4-3' ),
         (   4,  '2012-4-16' )

;
WITH  MonthsCTE
        AS ( SELECT
               1 AS ID ,
               DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS MonthStart ,
               DATEADD(YEAR, -1,
                       DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) AS YearEarlier
             UNION ALL
             SELECT
               ID + 1 ,
               DATEADD(MONTH, -1, MonthStart) ,
               DATEADD(YEAR, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, MonthStart))
             FROM
               MonthsCTE
             WHERE
               DATEADD(MONTH, -1, MonthStart) > DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())
           )
   SELECT
      MonthStart ,
      COUNT(#Events.EventTypeID)  AS TotalOccurances,
      COUNT(#Events.EventTypeID) /12 AS AverageOccurances
   FROM
      MonthsCTE
   LEFT OUTER JOIN #Events
   ON #Events.EventDate BETWEEN YearEarlier AND MonthStart
      AND #Events.EventTypeID = 4
   GROUP BY
      MonthStart


      DROP TABLE #Events
```

Above, I'm building a CTE (think temp table if you aren't familiar with them) that includes the last twelve months and the date a year before them.

Then the second query joins that table to your data, allowing any data that falls between the fields in the CTE.

Comment: hi thanks, but my table does not have ready to use values.. I must select a number of cases (x) where a statement is true. EG. number of records in my database where an incident has taken place (which I can determine by querying the value field for 'Incident'. Of these (x) es I want the moving average. So this month there might have been 2, last month 1, etc. up until 24 months ago.

Comment: yes, that is already in my query in the join condition: `yourTable.Description = 'Text here'` If you'd like my sample to match your data more closely, please edit your question to provide the relevant details of your table, and hopefully some sample data. And, yes, my query will average across multiple values per month.

Comment: Hi Jamie, ok here's the extremely simplified format of my table, including some fictional data that should give you a pretty good idea. 

Table "Events"
ID   EventTypeID   DATE
1    32            01/01/2012
2    4             01/20/2012
3    5             02/03/2012
4    4             02/15/2012
5    34            03/01/2012
6    4             04/03/2012
7    4             04/16/2012
etc

I want to query the moving average of the number of records that have event type number 4. So that would be 1 in January, 1 in February, none in March, 2 in April.

Thanks for your replies! Appreciate it! :)

Comment: The average of your sample data will always be less than .5: 4 events in 12 months will round to zero. Answer changed to get moving average and total number of occurrences anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the unionizing all of your table into one. query.AM i right. if so .

Combining results from multple queries can be done thru union queries for example. here is a query.

```
SELECT colA, colB FROM tableA WHERE colA > 1
UNION
SELECT colX, colA FROM tableB WHERE colA > 1
```

here are some of the samples could help you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqlunion.php

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/11/sql-server-difference-between-union-vs-union-all-optimal-performance-comparison/

Comment: hey thanks for your answer.. It does not work as i would like.. I can only define one column this way, is that correct? 

I need the results to be displayed like this:

MONTH        VALUE
september    5
august       3
july         1
etc...